# -sSL not functioning on Windows PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, python-poetry

I am attempting to install poetry, but I keep getting a strange error

When I enter:

```
PS C:\Users\[USER]> curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

I get:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'sSL'.
At line:1 char:6
+ curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
+      ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: Windows PowerShell ships with `curl` as a built-in alias for the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet. If you want to invoke `curl.exe`, spell it out fully: `curl.exe -sSL ...`